# Formatting sd card for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, operating-systems, partition

I am trying to install Raspbian OS on my Raspberry Pi. I have a 8 gb SD card which has two partitions. A 56 MB ntfs partition and a 7.34 GB fat32 partition (I badly messed up the partitioning while trying to install raspbian). Here is what it looks like in GParted:

[image]

Now whatever I do, I am not able to setup the OS on it. How do I partition it to be able to install the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unmount all the partition by separately selecting each partition in Gparted and right click and selecting `unmount`.
2. Once unmounted, delete all the partition. (right click --> delete option)
3. You should be able to see all 7.4 GiB as unallocated space.
4. Create new fat32 partition of 7.4 GiB by right clicking on unallocated space and selecting option `create...`
5. After doing all this, click on `green right` button in menu bar.

By now, your card should be reformatted as one 7.4 GiB fat32 partition.

Now, use `dd` from command prompt to burn .img as below.

`sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/image-file.img of=/dev/sdc` (DO NOT USE partition number 1,2,etc..). Make sure that partition is unmounted.

Hope it helps.